# Unable to add maven remote catalogue

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jersey, maven-archetype

I've been trying to create a maven project on eclipse but it brings up this error when trying to add jersey archetype:

Can't resolve Archetype org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes:jersey-quickstart-webapp:2.30.1
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Could not resolve artifact

I followed solutions online to create a remote catalog using: 
https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml

But when i verify it to download, it says "Remote Catalog is empty" any reason why its not working for me?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: Due to restricttions on my company network, it was preventing the archetypes from downloading.